# jupyter lab could not bring up on windows when using question mark?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

When using question mark, it brings up on windows by jupyter notebook but showing all  in cell by jupyter lab like below. I want lab could be like notebook.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shift+tab doesn't work?

Comment: @Prats yes,it works but I want to using mark to achieve it.

Comment: You could use `Contextual Help` option and move the tab to the bottom so that it is below there. You can also open an issue on https://github.com/jupyterlab/retrolab to get this function into Notebook v7 (which will ba based on retrolab and aims at UX compatibility with previous versions).

Answer (score 1):

You said above, "I want lab to be like notebook", but I don't think you are going to get what you want. The only difference I can see is that in Lab, the output is directly under the cell and other cells can be underneath it and in notebook it is in a window at the bottom of all cells.  You can copy and paste the text in either one.  Maybe the question is how to get the 'pager' window on the bottom in lab similar to notebook.

[Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyRNw.png)

versus

[Lab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuyB9.png)